# How do I fix “TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments” when using scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm pretty new to Python and was following a video tutorial on YouTube about how to scrape information on Amazon by using Scrapy.

Here's my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from ..items import AmazonItem

class AmazonproductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'amazonproduct'
    page_number = 2

    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.com/air-purifier/s?k=air+purifier&rh=p_n_condition-type%3A6461716011&qid=1570164390&ref=sr_pg_1']

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazonItem()

        product_name = response.css('#search .a-size-medium').css('::text').extract()
        product_price = response.css('.sg-col-6-of-24 .a-price-whole').css('::text').extract()
        product_reviews = response.css('.sg-col-12-of-28 .a-size-base').css('::text').extract()

        items['product_name'] = product_name
        items['product_price'] = product_price
        items['product_reviews'] = product_reviews

        yield items

        next_page = ['https://www.amazon.com/air-purifier/s?k=air+purifier&rh=p_n_condition-type%3A6461716011&page=' + str(AmazonproductSpider.page_number) + '&qid=1570164578&ref=sr_pg_2']
        if AmazonproductSpider.page_number <= 20:
            AmazonproductSpider.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)

        pass
```

I followed through the tutorial, ran my code, and got the information on the first page scaped successfully, but when Scrapy was scraping the other pages, and an error came up as follow:

```
2019-10-04 13:16:26 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET https://www.amazon.com/air-purifier/s?k=air+purifier&rh=p_n_condition-type%3A6461716011> (referer: None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 102, in iter_errback
    yield next(it)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/offsite.py", line 29, in process_spider_output
    for x in result:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/referer.py", line 339, in <genexpr>
    return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/urllength.py", line 37, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 84, in evaluate_iterable
    for r in iterable:
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/spidermiddlewares/depth.py", line 58, in <genexpr>
    return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
  File "/Users/andrealien/Desktop/Work/Amazon_airpurifier/amazon/amazon/spiders/amazonproduct.py", line 27, in parse
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 158, in follow
    cb_kwargs=cb_kwargs,
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/__init__.py", line 125, in follow
    url = self.urljoin(url)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/http/response/text.py", line 82, in urljoin
    return urljoin(get_base_url(self), url)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 488, in urljoin
    base, url, _coerce_result = _coerce_args(base, url)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/urllib/parse.py", line 120, in _coerce_args
    raise TypeError("Cannot mix str and non-str arguments")
TypeError: Cannot mix str and non-str arguments
```

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?
Thank you all in advance for reading my questions!

Comment: what exact line is causing the error, I can't re duplicate error

Comment: @wishmaster Hi, thanks for replying! I don't really know what is causing the error either, but it might be worth mentioning that I installed Scrapy through conda, and my scrapy project was built on PyCharm... Not sure if this would cause any errors

Answer (score 1):

in your code next_page is a list [] , it should just 1 string with a url to follow.

try to run this example and see if its working
i moved AmazonItem to the same file just to make it short, its better off in a different file

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Item, Field


# from ..items import AmazonItem
class AmazonItem(Item):
    product_name = Field()
    product_price = Field()
    product_reviews = Field()


class AmazonproductSpider(Spider):
    name = 'amazonproduct'
    page_number = 2
    base_url = 'https://www.amazon.com'
    start_urls = [
        f'{base_url}/air-purifier/s?k=air+purifier&rh=p_n_condition-type%3A6461716011&qid=1570164390&ref=sr_pg_1'
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        items = AmazonItem()

        items['product_name'] = response.css('#search .a-size-medium').css('::text').get()
        items['product_price'] = response.css('.sg-col-6-of-24 .a-price-whole').css('::text').get()
        items['product_reviews'] = response.css('.sg-col-12-of-28 .a-size-base').css('::text').get()

        yield items

        next_page = f'{AmazonproductSpider.base_url}' \
                    f'/air-purifier/s?k=air+purifier&rh=p_n_condition-type%3A6461716011&page=' \
                    f'{AmazonproductSpider.page_number}&qid=1570164578&ref=sr_pg_2'

        if AmazonproductSpider.page_number <= 20:
            AmazonproductSpider.page_number += 1
            yield response.follow(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably pass `str` to the first argument of `follow`

```
next_page = 'https://www.amazon.com/air-purifier/s?k=air+purifier&rh=p_n_condition-type%3A6461716011&page=' + str(AmazonproductSpider.page_number) + '&qid=1570164578&ref=sr_pg_2'
if AmazonproductSpider.page_number <= 20:
    AmazonproductSpider.page_number += 1
    yield response.follow(next_page, callback = self.parse)
```

See: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.follow

Comment: What does it mean? Is there any way that I can change my code to resolve the error? Sorry...I'm really new to python...

Comment: look at `next_page ` value in my answer, that is what you need to change